# CMake generates project twice

Tags: cmake

I'm grouping sources in folders by some rules and I want to be able to individually test each group in isolation for faster iteration. To do so I want to CMake to generate one executable for each group. I simplified the project structure to:

```
root
    build
    group_1
        CMakeLists.txt
        group_1_file_1.cpp
        group_1_tests
            CMakeLists.txt
            group_1_file_1_tests.cpp
```

where `group_1/CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
SET(group_1_srcs
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/group_1_file_1.cpp
)

#Generate standalone application for unit tests when cmake is started with this CMakeLists as root
IF(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)
    ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("group_1_tests/")
ENDIF()
```

and `group_1/group_1_tests/CMakeLists.txt` is

```
PROJECT(group_1_tests)
SET(group_1_tests_srcs
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/group_1_file_1_tests.cpp
)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} "${group_1_tests_srcs}" "${group_1_srcs}")
```

Running `cmake ../group_1` from `root/build/` generates me the project I want, `root/build/group_1_tests/group_1_tests.sln`, but also `root/build/Project.sln` with the same files & settings as the previous one.

Can you please explain why this projects gets generate and how may I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in [the `project()` command documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html):

> The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file for a project must contain a literal, direct call to the `project()` command ... If no such call exists CMake will implicitly add one to the top that enables the default languages (`C` and `CXX`).

So `Project` is the default project's name. And from that point onward CMake generates a `.sln` solution for all `CMakeLists.txt` containing another `project()` command.

I would recommend you ignore the root solution file (if you don't want it) or restructure your project to have a single `project()` command call in the root `CMakeList.txt` (since your sub-level project won't run standalone without the top-level project anyway).

**References**

- [CMake Commit: ENH: generate a sln and dsw file for each sub project in a project](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/5ccfaefb48758c7af0df011df160add1df1e1b53)